# How to see misspelling suggestions when spell checking in Jupyter Notebook markdown?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Using Jupiter Notebook [nbextentions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) I can enable spell checking within markdown cells.

It conveniently highlights bad spelling, but I cant see any correct suggestions.

It uses [typo.js](https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js)

...within which there is support for misspelling suggestions:

> To get suggested corrections for a misspelled word, do this:
>
> var array_of_suggestions = dictionary.suggest("mispeling");

How can I use this to see misspelling suggestions in Jupyter Notebooks ?